# How to find line count of file in Haskell? (how to remove for loop?)

Tags: haskell

Aspiring haskeller here. I wrote a script to take a filepath argument, read the contents where each line will be a relative filepath, and count the lines of each filepath and print it to the command line. It relies on `System.Directory.Internal.Prelude.for_` to loop through the file's contents and print each length to the console.

- Question 1: How would you remove the `for` loop?
- Question 2: If `getFileLength` had a signature of `FilePath -> IO(Maybe(Int)), how would you refactor the program? (Does this question make sense?)

```
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import Data.Char
import System.Directory.Internal.Prelude (for_)

main = do
  (configPath:_) <- getArgs
  configContents <- readFile configPath 
  let filePaths = lines configContents
  for_ filePaths (\path -> do getFileLength path)

getFileLength :: FilePath -> IO()
getFileLength path = do
  contents <- readFile path
  putStrLn $ "- [ ] " ++ path ++ " (" ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ ")"
```

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://0xd34df00d.me/posts/2020/02/beating-c-with-20-lines-of-haskell.html

Comment: Use `Data.Foldable.for_` instead of some for variant from an "internal" module. Also, `(\path -> do getFileLength path)` is a complicated way to write `getFileLength`. (BTW, I'd change that function name, it sounds counter intuitive)

Comment: Why do you want to remove the for loop? It looks perfectly idiomatic to me (up to the import needed for it, as mentioned by other folks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) or [**`traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (configPath:_) <- getArgs
  configContents <- readFile configPath
  mapM_ getFileLength (lines configContents)
```

or:

```
import Data.Foldable(traverse_)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (configPath:_) <- getArgs
  configContents <- readFile configPath 
  traverse_ getFileLength (lines configContents)
```

Comment: @jks612, note that `for_`, `mapM_`, and `traverse_` are just different names for the same function (except for the ordering of the arguments to `for_`).  So, it's not like `for_` is a non-idiomatic "loop" that needs to be fixed by replacing it with a "more functional" `traverse_`.